# Multiple Verilog Errors in Always block

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to create an arithmetic logic unit in Verilog. I'm fairly new to it, so forgive me if I'm a bit ignorant as to how things work. Im getting several errors when trying to compile my project:

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(45) near text: â. Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(45) near text: "â";  expecting an operand. Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(45) near text: . Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(45) near text: . Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10149): Verilog HDL Declaration error at alu.v(49): identifier "addA2" is already declared in the present scope
Error (10149): Verilog HDL Declaration error at alu.v(49): identifier "addA1" is already declared in the present scope
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(49) near text: "}";  expecting ";". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10149): Verilog HDL Declaration error at alu.v(51): identifier "ab2" is already declared in the present scope
Error (10149): Verilog HDL Declaration error at alu.v(51): identifier "ab1" is already declared in the present scope
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(51) near text: "}";  expecting ";". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10149): Verilog HDL Declaration error at alu.v(53): identifier "abvo" is already declared in the present scope
Error (10149): Verilog HDL Declaration error at alu.v(53): identifier "abv" is already declared in the present scope
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(53) near text: "}";  expecting ";". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at alu.v(66) near text: ")";  expecting ";". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
Error (10112): Ignored design unit "subALU" at alu.v(24) due to previous errors
Error (10112): Ignored design unit "rippleCarryAdder" at alu.v(75) due to previous errors
Error (10112): Ignored design unit "fullAdder" at alu.v(116) due to previous errors
Error (10112): Ignored design unit "sevenSegDecoder" at alu.v(128) due to previous errors
```

I'm kind of at a loss as to what's wrong, and was wondering if anyone had any insight. Here's the module throwing errors:

```
module subALU(A, B, func, ALUout);
    input [3:0] A;
    input [3:0] B;
    input [2:0] func;
    output [7:0] ALUout;

    //A+1
    reg [3:0] addA1;
    reg addA2;
    rippleCarryAdder add1(.A(A), .B(4'b0001), .cin(0), .s(addA1), .cout(addA2));

    //A+B
    reg [3:0] ab1;
    reg ab2;
    rippleCarryAdder add2(.A(A), .B(B), .cin(0), .s(ab1), .cout(ab2));

    //A+B using Verilog
    reg [3:0] abv;
    reg abvo;
    fourBitAdd add3(.X(A), .Y(B), .C(abv), .overflow(abvo));

    always @(∗)
    begin
        case (func)
            //A + 1
            3'b000: ALUout[7:0] = {3'b000, addA2, addA1};
            //A + B (Using rippleCarryAdder)
            3'b001: ALUout = {3'b000, ab2, ab1};
            //A + B (Using Verilog arithmetic)
            3'b010: ALUout = {3'b000, abvo, abv};
            //A XOR B in lower 4 bits, A OR B in higher 4
            3'b011: ALUout = {A | B, A ^ B};
            //A and B reduction OR
            3'b100: ALUout = {7'b0000000, |(A|B)};
            //A in leftmost 4 bits, B in rightmost 4 bits 
            3'b101: ALUout = {A, B};
            //Display 0
            default: ALUout = 8'b00000000
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

If anyone could let me know what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write it this way

```
module subALU(A, B, func, ALUout);
input [3:0] A;
input [3:0] B;
input [2:0] func;
output reg[7:0] ALUout;

//A+1
wire [3:0] addA1;
wire addA2;
rippleCarryAdder add1(.A(A), .B(4'b0001), .cin(0), .s(addA1), .cout(addA2));

//A+B
wire [3:0] ab1;
wire ab2;
rippleCarryAdder add2(.A(A), .B(B), .cin(0), .s(ab1), .cout(ab2));

//A+B using Verilog
wire [3:0] abv;
wire abvo;
fourBitAdd add3(.X(A), .Y(B), .C(abv), .overflow(abvo));

always @(∗)
begin
    case (func)
        //A + 1
        3'b000: ALUout[7:0] = {3'b000, addA2, addA1};
        //A + B (Using rippleCarryAdder)
        3'b001: ALUout = {3'b000, ab2, ab1};
        //A + B (Using Verilog arithmetic)
        3'b010: ALUout = {3'b000, abvo, abv};
        //A XOR B in lower 4 bits, A OR B in higher 4
        3'b011: ALUout = {A | B, A ^ B};
        //A and B reduction OR
        3'b100: ALUout = {7'b0000000, |(A|B)};
        //A in leftmost 4 bits, B in rightmost 4 bits 
        3'b101: ALUout = {A, B};
        //Display 0
        default: ALUout = 8'b00000000
    endcase
end
```

endmodule